# Unable to launch Android Application using Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am trying to perform a test on Native Application (Calculator) but Application is not launching from Appium. Refer below for complete details:

Refer below for details:
Appium Server:

[image]

Device connection:
[image]

Appium and Selenium-java Dependecy:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code to Application launch:

```
   public void startApp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "TKS44SS8DAVWNRMZ");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.bbkcalculator");  
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.bbkcalculator.Calculator");
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub");
    System.out.println("Hardcoded URL: " + url);
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Please correct me in above code and set up. Let me know if any other details required. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add one more capability and try again.

cap.setCapability("udid" , "TKS44SS8DAVWNRMZ");

It is required for real devices.

Comment: it is required for any device